# One combo box for two queries Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a form that needs to use two combo boxes but the values in the second combo should come from two different tables based on the first combo selection. If I select option A in combo_1 I want to list all the agency names from tblRefAgency in combo_2. If I select option B in combo_1 I want to list all of the carriers from tblrefCarrier in combo_2. I can add VB code to hide/show two different combo boxes and then overlap them, but I feel I should be able to do this in a query. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are dealing with a single form, you can easily set the row source of the second combo in the After Update event of the first combo.

```
If Me.Combo1=1 Then
    Me.combo2.RowSource = "SELECT ID, Description FROM tblRefAgency 
End If
```

If the 2nd combo is bound to a field, you will also have to set the combo in the current event to ensure that data is displayed properly.

Comment: That is exactly what i was hoping for. Thank you Remou!